# Will grape ivy harm oak and sumac if allowed to spread?

Tags: diagnosis

I see what I believe to be grape ivy growing on oaks, sumacs and other chaparral in the San Diego back country.

Will this harm those plants if allowed to spread?

Answer (score 4):

If it is one of the Vitis sp., especially Vitis californica, then it is a native and best left alone. So you should try to find out the species to be sure.

The English Ivy is definitely being discouraged in California because it covers the ground and will not allow any other species, especially low light natives to grow.

Neither kind, will typically affect Oaks. Chaparral and Sumac may be choked if the non-natives mound at a certain height and cut off both light and ground to spread.

You said "back country", so it is best to identify the species through this site, Cal-IPC or the California Chaparral Institute and then decide whether to allow it to spread or not. Natives are best allowed to do as they please. If non-native, you may want to take the usual prescribed action.